# What is the difference between the "lib" and "library" folder?

Tags: python

Does anyone know the difference between the lib and library folder? example please see this website; https://github.com/ansible/ansible

Is it just a name difference?

Comment: I checked them and they belong to Python, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any *real* standard.

Generally speaking: `lib` directories contain software libraries, and `library` doesn't have any standard meaning.

In this case, `lib/` contains the Ansible library its self, where `library/` contains scripts which users of Ansible might find useful; the scripts depend on Ansible, but Ansible does not depend on the scripts.